# New transactional email notification?

Tags: email, order-status, transactional-mail

I added 2 more status for the orders, and I would like to automatically send transactional email when the orders reach this status.

I added the Email templates, but have no idea what I have to do to automatically send these emails.

Comment: I managed to do it using this tutorial :
[link]http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/[/link]
but now, I would like to send an email using a template declared in the Admin/transactional email menu…
How can I access these templates?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it !

If it can help somebody, here is my Observer.php

```
<?php
class Mine_Custmail_Model_Observer
{
    public function invoicedStatusChange($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();

        /*if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)*/
        if ($orderStatus == 'waitingmanufacturing')
            $this->_sendStatusMail($order);
    }

    private  function _sendStatusMail($order)
    {
        $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
        $sender  = array(
                'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),
                'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            );
        $customerName = $order->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname() . " " . $order->getShippingAddress()->getLastname();
        $customerEmail = $order->getPayment()->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
        $customerLanguage = $order->getStoreId();

         if ($customerLanguage == 1)
         {$template = 12;}
         else {$template = 13;}

        $vars = Array( 'order' => $order );

        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 

        Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional($template, $sender, $customerEmail, $customerName, $vars, $storeId);

    }
}
```